Remote clickhouse error: DB::Exception: There's no column '__table1.event_params.key' in table '__table1'
I use remoteSecure function to query remote table from one clickhouse server to another. We have two enviroments PROD and DEV from where remote queries are sent. PROD clickhouse has version 23.7.3.14, DEV has version 24.5.3.5, remote server has version 24.8.8.17. Remote tables have nested columns so I can access it using dot notation. Name of nested column is  event_params.key. When I query remote table from PROD enviroment I get result with no issues but when I do the same on DEV I get error

DB::Exception: There's no column '__table1.event_params.key' in table '__table1': While processing __table1.event_params.key AS event_params.key. (UNKNOWN_IDENTIFIER)

I have no tables with name "__table1" , looks like this is some system metadata name because I use remoteSecure function. I can retrieve data using order number of element of list  like following event_params[1] but this is not what I want. I need to get data using dot notation and nested column name. What can be a issue? Maybe some settings should be turned on?

look to EXPLAIN SYNTAX, looks like your query was rewritten, check system.query_log on remote server to see how exactly your
try to add SETTINGS allow_experimental_analyzer=0

could you provide table structure and SQL query without sensitive credentials?
